# How to merge elements of vectors in new vector in R

Tags: r

I want to extract the elements of each vector and get new vector that attached the elements

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
y<-c(w,w,w,w)
z<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

Expected result

```
xyz<-c(1w1,2w2,3w3,4w4)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think a pretty straightforward `paste0` will get it done here.

```
> x <- 1:4; y <- rep("w", 4); z <- 1:4
> (xyz <- paste0(x, y, z))
# [1] "1w1" "2w2" "3w3" "4w4"
```

`cat` would also work,

```
> cat(paste0(x, y, z), sep = ",")
# 1w1,2w2,3w3,4w4
```

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
as.character(interaction(x,y,z,sep=""))
#[1] "1w1" "2w2" "3w3" "4w4"
```

Comment: Don't think I've ever used `interaction`.  +1